# All TextView in RecyclerView displaying same data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview

I have an arraylist containing 100 words. I want to assign each word to an individual textview of RecyclerView, but all the textviews of my Recyclerview show the same data, i.e the last word.

```
for(String s:arraylist){
    viewholder.textview.setText(s);
}
```

Above is my Adapter Code for RecyclerView. How should I resolve this?

Comment: check out this link may be helpful https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: post code from recycleview adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
viewholder.textview.setText(arraylist.get(position));
```

Instead of

```
for(String s:arraylist){
   viewholder.textview.setText(s);
}
```

Comment: Will it create 100 textview in my recyclerview?

Answer (score -1):

Use following below code for Set the values in `textview` from the `ArrayList` in `RecyclerView.

```
viewholder.textview.setText(arrayList.get(position));
```

I hope this may help you,